# Which phrase extraction tool is the state of art now?

Tags: nlp, information-extraction

I know of the following open source tools, but I haven't found any comparisons of how good they are respectively.
Tools with ready to use phrase extraction:

- KEA
- MAUI (http://code.google.com/p/maui-indexer/)
- Dragon, xTract (http://dragon.ischool.drexel.edu/xtract.asp)
- Lingpipe (http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/interestingPhrases/read-me.html)
- Mahout (https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/collocations.html)
- Anything else

Did anyone ever see such a comparison?

Comment: with "phrase extraction", do you mean "sentence splitting" or "sentence tokenization"?

Answer (score 4):

[MAUI](http://code.google.com/p/maui-indexer/) outperforms KEA on my experiments.
There is a comparison on unsupervised automatic key phrase extraction methods (Coling 2010 paper). But they don't analyse supervised methods, I'm planning to do that in a near future.

In addition, I've also explored a richer set of features which improved the performance of automatic Key Phrase Extraction which is still far from perfect. I might release the extended version of MAUI with those extensions next year.

Please read the following papers or email me more details:

[Supervised Topical Key Phrase Extraction of News Stories using Crowdsourcing, Light Filtering and Co-reference Normalization](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lmarujo/publications/lmarujo_LREC_2012.pdf)

[Keyphrase Cloud Generation of Broadcast News](http://www.inesc-id.pt/ficheiros/publicacoes/7588.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I like [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php) because it has a command line tool that is really easy to use

Comment: How you can extract phrases with mallet? i.e. there are topic modeling = clustering, but as I am aware there are not key phrase extraction from large corpra